# Combine Laravel and Wordpress via htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel

I have a standard Larvael folder structure, and I want to have a Wordpress blog in /blog folder.
I am on a shared hosing, so I am using this htaccess at root of my domain to rewrite all requests to /public:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Then I thought I'd put blog in the root and just not do the rewriting if the route starts with blog:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

But that didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Petar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And with that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Because URI begin with `/`